# MySQL sudden loss of data

Tags: mysql

It is second time that records are lost in MySQL specific table.

I am having Master-Slave MySQL replication.

For the 1st time, one of my tables partially lost records on 6 May.
The weird part is, the Master instance records loss is not replicated to the Slave. It couldn't be SQL injection or script issue. I can't really remember much details as it is 2 months ago.

And recently (2nd time), the data loss happens again in another table. The data lost for records after 2015-06-05, and about 60% of the records gone. This time, the Slave has the data loss too.

I checked the Slave mysqlbinlog file, there is no `DELETE FROM table` command executed during that period.

Both tables are InnoDB, running MySQL server in Ubuntu instance.

I realised the data loss issue only after multiple users reporting the software behaving incorrectly.

May I know what happen to MySQL? This is frightening if the data can be lost out of nowhere. I managed to recover the data with daily backup, but this is definitely not a good option.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some table with a `REFERENCES` contraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE`?  See [13.1.18.6 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). Deleting from a *parent* (referenced) table might have deleted from some *children* (referencing) tables, if there's an `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: I did not assign any Foreign Key.

Comment: I'd [`CHECK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/check-table.html) tables... this looks like something is corrupted, and this corruption is made visible when some row is inserted or updated.

Comment: Perhaps add a trigger to record the date-time and username whenever a delete-row action is taken on that table, as a way to debug. While I don't know about the capabilities of MySQL, certainly you could do this in Postgres or other such databases.